# how to remove vertical separator in tab in android

Tags: android

I have made an app which has tabs like in HomeActivity, there is also space between these tabs, can anyone suggest how to remove this space and also there is a grey line beneath the tabs how can that be removed?

Can anyone help?

Comment: in style.xml create theme for your activity and use item as per your link that item to your theme and apply that theme to your activity so automaticaly it will apply to your tab too...

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme hey i got answer use 

<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:showDividers="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: gud i thought u want to change its color

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme no i just want to remove the vertical separator Thank you ..